# How to create a Spring Session when using a custom filter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I'm using Spring Boot 3.1.1.

I've created a custom filter which lets users authenticate using a POST request to the path "/login" with a JSON body containing their credentials.

I would expect Spring session to be notified of a successful authentication and create a related session. But it doesn't create any session (not even an anonymous one).

Here's my filter:

```
public class JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    record LoginRequest(String username, String password) {
    }

    public JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"), authenticationManager);
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new OkAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            var inputStream = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(request.getInputStream());
            var loginRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputStream, LoginRequest.class);

            var authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.username(), loginRequest.password());

            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the success handler:

```
public class OkAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(200);
        String body = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new UserCtrl.DisplayUser(authentication.getName()));
        response.getWriter().print(body);
    }
}
```

In my `build.gradle.kts`, I have

```
implementation("org.springframework.session:spring-session-core")
implementation("org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc")
```

Which according to Spring documentation should be everything that's needed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/boot-jdbc.html. Though, I did try adding the annotation `@EnableJdbcHttpSession` or the property `spring.session.store-type=jdbc`.

While experimenting with Spring Session, I was able to get a session, but an anonymous one, column principal_name was empty in the database and request would be authenticated as an anonymous user.
Also, I could see in my database logs the request running every minute or so:

```
DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < $1
```

Comment: It seems a session is created on a 403 response... Maybe Spring Session isn't called because of my success handler???